# bootstrap modal is not working. I have made sure everything is okay but still not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

here is my code

```
<a href="#logout" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a><!--link to the modal-->
```

and here is the modal

```
<!--the pop up box to look like this-->
<div class="modal fade" id="logout" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="alert alert-error">Are you sure you want to Logout?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa   fa-remove"></i>&nbsp;NO</button>
     <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-check">   </i>&nbsp;Yes</a>
    </div>
</div><!--end modal-->
```

Answer (score 0):

> Bootstrap CDN
>   CSS

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

> JS

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

> Trigger the modal with a button

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logout">modal window</button>
```

> Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="logout" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-body  modal-lg">
     <div class="alert alert-error">Are you sure you want to Logout?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa   fa-remove"></i>&nbsp;NO</button>
     <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-check">   </i>&nbsp;Yes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

> javascript , if want to do more changes with javascript. but it will work without it.

```
 $(document).ready(function ()  
          {

              $('#modal_name').modal({
                  show: false,
                  backdrop: 'static',
                  keyboard: false
                });
          });
```

> JS Fiddle
>   [Check this fiddle, It's Your Code](https://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/dgoqgu23/10/)
>
> I guess, you are using lower version of jQuery, use this one. it will work [jQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js)

Comment: i have done the same..but nothing so far...i have included all the necessary bootstrap and jquery files but it doesnt work

Comment: ok, just place this modal window. and test it. and place a CDN of bootstrap and jquery too.. and then let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Are your scripts are ordered like this:

```
<!-- MAKE SURE JQUERY IS BEFORE BOOTSTRAP -->
<script src="/path/to/jquery/"></script>
<script src="/path/to/bootstrap/"></script>
```